# Disable the dropdown value which already exist in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anyone guide me to get a solution. For example , there is a dropdown down in the form contains some animals name. If the user select the one animal from that, it saved in dropdown. Again in selection process, that saved data want to become disabled. The other options only able to select. This is the solution i want.

Comment: Can you supply tried code with expected and actual result?

Comment: f.selelect :year, (Time.now.year...Time.now.year+10).to_a. Inthis case, if i select 2016  that wont come again in the drop down..or disable in dropdown

Comment: Where this animal value stored ?

Comment: Animals concept is just an example.in that year concept, the history of office planning saved. Once the year saved, that year doesnot comes again

Comment: Agreed but where this animal value stored ? Is there any db or UI saved value known from anywhere which you ignore either java script level from db query level?

Comment: That may be a coming years also.once it should be created, that year does not show in dropdown list

Comment: Saved in MySQL database

Comment: Please Check rules of asking question and please next time provide some code which you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a helper method for your view, or you could set instance variables in your controller but here is some pseudo code to get you going.

```
def disabled_animals
   Animal.where(already_selected: true).pluck(:name)
end

def selectable_animals
  Animal.all.pluck(:name) - disabled_animals
end
```

the idea is to get 2 arrays, one without the disabled animals and one with the disabled animals and pass those to your `select` helper method, then you could do something like this in your view.:

`select("post", "animal", selectable_animals, {disabled: disabled_animals})`

Which would produce this:

```
<select name="post[animal]" id="post_animal">   
  <option value=""></option>   
  <option value="joke">joke</option>   
  <option value="poem">poem</option>   
  <option disabled="disabled" value="zebra">zebra</option> 
</select>
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: @Prabha , glad it does. Could you kindly vote the question up? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Highlevel idea:

```
Get selected value from UI and pass it to mysql query to exclude it
```

## Code:

## Get value from dropdown through jQuery:

```
var selectedAnimal = $('.animals').find('#animal option:selected').text().trim();
```

> Please change according to your UI

## Pass selected animal in query to exclude it

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `animal` FROM " . $animalTable . " where animal <> '<selectedAnimal>';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ( $num_rows > 0 ) {
    for ($row_no=1; $row_no <= $num_rows; $row_no++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $dropdown.= "<option value='" .$row['animal']. "'>" .$row['animal']. "</option>";
    }
}

echo "<select class='dropdownselect' id='animal'> " .$dropdown. "</select>";
```

> Please change according to your query and language used